# Backup iphone Photo album

Tags: iphone, ios

How is it posssible to backup iphone photo ablums?
Unfortunately i can only backup all photos in one folder which does not make sense.

Thanks.

Andi

Comment: Are you a PC or Mac user ?

Answer (score 1):

You can backup all your personal data on your iPhone in one time. iTunes can do that for you.

You can "Back up" all your iPhone photos, text messages, contacts, notes, etc. on iTunes. And when you lost them somehow, you can easily restore them.
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1414

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible,
The `tmp` and `cache` directories are periodically cleaned up by iOS. If the images are for general use, or use the camera roll. However if these images are intended just for the scope of your app, you can still safely store them in the Documents directory, you just have to include an "exclude from iCloud backup" function call to each file after saving, in order to prevent Apple rejecting your app for using too much iCloud space. Of course there's a trade-off, disabling this means the user will lose their photos anyway should they delete the app or get another device.

In disable iCloud backup on a file, there are methods for iOS versions > 5.0.

Saving it in `NSCacheDirectory` for below or equal to iOS 5.0. While later versions you can save it via `NSDocumentsDirectory`. Here are some projects you can try multiple image picker: [AGImagePickerController](https://github.com/arturgrigor/AGImagePickerController) && [ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController).

Then save it in what I told you above. Hope this helps.